# Как установить Windows на 3ТБ диск при классическом биосе?

Tags: windows, установка, gpt

При классическом биосе инсталлятор Windows позволяет установку только на mbr-диски.

Гуглится только про конвертирование диска в соответствующий формат. Но mbr не позволяет использовать больше 2 ТБ, соответственно, в таком случае более 700 ГБ остаются неиспользуемыми, что, естественно, не подходит.

Есть диск на 2 ТБ - первичный загрузчик находится на нём. Но систему хочу поставить на другой. Скорее всего, основным загрузчиком будет grub (хотя во время моих экспериментов им выступал загрузчик десятки).

Попробовал разметить диск в mbr, установить Windows 10, потом сконвертировать в gpt - система загрузиться не смогла, но позволила вызвать загрузчик одной из других систем (без возможности выбора, по нажатию F9).

Comment: Хм, а разбить диск на тома не вариант?

Comment: @VladD, mbr не позволяет адресовать разделы дальше границы в 2 ТБ. Т. е. я теряю кусок диска 3*10^12 - 2*2^40 = 800976744448 байт = 746 ГБ независимо от разбиения на разделы.

Comment: @VladD, или я чего-то не знаю и том это не раздел?

Comment: Хм. У меня дома есть винт в 3Тб, размеченный под Windows 7 (NTFS), и он весь видится без проблем. Причём он _не_ разбит на разделы/тома/whatever.

Comment: @VladD, 1. У тебя классический биос или UEFI? 2. "Размеченный под" означает, что на нём установлен Windows 7? 3. Разбит как? mbr или gpt?

Comment: 1) Сейчас UEFI, но раньше был классический BIOS, и на нём работало. Но система стартовала не с этого диска, а с другого, маленького. 2) Нет, только под данные. 3) Mbr.

Comment: То есть система видела большой диск, несмотря на то, что на нём был MBR, который не мог адресовать его размер в полном объёме.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37056/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladd).